# Cannot change button value by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

After applying the
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css and
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js

the text of the button cannot be changed by scripting `$(this).val('new value');`

Do anyone have similar experience and have the solution?

DEMO can be tried from [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yckelvin/Rz2sJ/)

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit_btn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).val('Processing ...');
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            url: "echo/json",
            complete: function (HttpRequest, textStatus) {
                $(this).val('Create');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="call.php" method="POST" id="form1" name="form1">
    <input type="text" name="campname" id="campname">
    <textarea id="longdesc" name="longdesc"></textarea>
    <input type="text" name="vercode" id="vercode" />
    <input type="submit" value="Create" id="submit_btn" />
</form>
```

Comment: work if not applying query.mobile-1.3.2.min.css

Comment: dont use `.ready()` in jQM, instead use [jQM events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/1.3/category/events/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final applying `$('#button').prev().text('your new text');` work.

Just don't understanding why use `.prev()` before changing the text.

Comment: because `button` is wrapped in div, the `.prev()` element is a `span.ui-bt-inner` that wraps another `span.ui-btn-text`. Doing this will replace `span.ui-btn-text` with _next text_ string, which is wrong. Use `.button("refresh")`

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this,

```
 $(".ui-btn-text").text('Processing ...');
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#submit_btn').click(function (e) {        
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".ui-btn-text").text('Processing ...');
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $('#form1').serialize(),
        url: "echo/json",
        complete: function (HttpRequest, textStatus) {
           $(".ui-btn-text").text('Create');
        }
    });
    return false;
   });
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Rz2sJ/4/

Comment: If reset button exit in form, value of reset button will also be changed. http://jsfiddle.net/yckelvin/Rz2sJ/5/

Comment: it can be done dynamically without the need to dig deep into classes.

Answer (score 2):

By the time the AJAX callback runs, `this` as a keyword has lost its context.  You need to assign it to a variable to retain the reference.  Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit_btn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var button = $(this);
        button.val('Processing ...');
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            url: "echo/json",
            complete: function (HttpRequest, textStatus) {
                button.val('Create');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: -1 sorry, it's a jQM widget issue not Ajax one. Plus, `.ready()` shouldn't be used in jQM. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 2):

You're working with [`.button()`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/1.3/button/) widget of jQuery Mobile. `<button>` is converted into a div to give it a new look by jQuery Mobile.

When doing any changes to `<button>` or `<a>`, you need to [*refresh*](http://api.jquerymobile.com/1.3/button/#method-refresh) that element to re-apply styles.

All you need to do is:

```
$(".selector").val('Processing ...').button("refresh");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/zcYj9/)**