# change button text in js/ajax after mp4 =>mp3 conversion in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, upload, progress-bar

I am working on **html table rows (which is two at this moment)**  as shown below in which on button click:

**=>** **JS/jQuery** code is called (where **Go** text changes to **Converting**)  
**=>** and then **convert.php** script through AJAX where conversion of **mp4 into mp3** happens.

> html/php code:

```
  <?php  foreach ($programs as $key => $program) {  ?> 
       <tr data-index="<?php echo $key; ?>">
          <td><input type="submit"  id="go-btn" name="go-button" value="Go" data-id="<?php echo $key; ?>" ></input></td>
       </tr>
    <?php }?>
```

> convert.php:

```
 $f = $mp4_files[$_POST['id']];
 $parts = pathinfo($f); 
 switch ($parts['extension'])
 {  
     case 'mp4' :
         $filePath = $src_dir . DS . $f;
         system('C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i ' . $filePath . ' -map 0:2 -ac 1 ' . $destination_dir . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3', $result);    
         print_r("Hello World");
         break;                  
 }
```

> JS/jQuery code:

```
$("input[name='go-button']").click( function() {

  // Change the text of the button, and disable
  $(this).val("Converting").attr("disabled", "true");

});
```

As soon as the button is clicked from the **html/php Code** above, the text gets changed from **Go** to **Converting** in the UI because I have added JS/jQuery code in my codebase but this JS/jQuery code which I have added just change the text only. **It doesn't actually know that the Conversion is happening in the background**.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what modification I need to do in the **JS/jQuery** code above so that UI actually knows that conversion is happening in the background.

Probably, we need to add make establish some connection between **JS/jQuery** and php code above but I am not sure how we can do that.

Comment: Your question isn't completely clear.  How do you think it should look if the "_UI actually knows that conversion is happening_"? Do you want to see "Go" -> "Converting" -> "Converted"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's fix the html.  You don't need `name` or `id` attributes on your button and they won't be unique because you are writing them in a loop.  Just replace them with `class="converter"`.  The `<input>` tag doesn't need a closing `</input>`.

A `submit` type button has a default behavior (which you don't want to combine with an ajax request). You can either use `e.preventDefault();` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20788544/2943403) or change the tag to something that does not fire a form submission.

Untested Codes:

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input.converter").click(function (e) {        
        e.preventDefault();
        let btn = $(this);
        btn.val("Converting").attr("disabled", "true");
        $.ajax({
            cache:    false,
            type:     "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data:     {id: btn.data('id')},
            url:      "convert.php",
            success:  function(response) {
                btn.val(response.message).attr("disabled", response.message == "Converted" ? "false" : "true");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
                console.log("Request failed: " + status);
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
                console.log("Done. No matter the outcome");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

php

```
if (empty($mp4_files[$_POST['id']])) {
    exit(json_encode(['message' => 'Failed']);
} 
$f = $mp4_files[$_POST['id']];
$parts = pathinfo($f); 
switch ($parts['extension'])
{  
    case 'mp4' :
        $filePath = $src_dir . DS . $f;
        system('C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i ' . $filePath . ' -map 0:2 -ac 1 ' . $destination_dir . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3', $result);    
        exit(json_encode(['message' => 'Converted']);
} 
exit(json_encode(['message' => 'Invalid File Type']);
```

---

Here's a quick demo (tested locally to work):

main.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function (e) {        
        e.preventDefault();
        let btn = $(this);
        btn.html("Converting...").attr("disabled", "true");
        $.ajax({
            cache:    false,
            type:     "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data:     {id: btn.data('id')},
            url:      "convert.php",
            success:  function(response) {
                btn.html(response.message)
                   .attr("disabled", response.message != "Bad"); // re-enables if Bad
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i) {
    echo "<div>{$i}: <button data-id=\"{$i}\">Convert</button></div>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

convert.php

```
<?php
$lookup = [
    'Good',
    'Bad'
];
sleep(1);
echo json_encode(['message' => $lookup[$_POST['id']] ?? 'Error']);
```

How it performs:

------------------------------------------- enabled -> disabled...... -> disabled

- Button #1 Text Progression: Convert -> Converting... -> Good
- Button #2 Text Progression: Convert -> Converting... -> Bad (enabled)
- Button #3 Text Progression: Convert -> Converting... -> Error

Comment: The other thing which I am thinking is when I am open the same webpage on different machine, it should know that file has been completed **(meaning conversion of mp4=>mp3 is done)**. 

On opening the page on different machine, **Go button text** shows up again belonging to particular file which is not right because that file is already completed .

Comment: That is a new requirement for your posted question.  You are not meant to change your requirements after posting.  You can post a new question if you like.  If I have resolved the original question, let's stitch this one up before moving on.

Comment: I've added a couple of php scripts to show a quick demo of what I think you want.  As for checking what has been already converted, you will need to save any newly converted rows to a database table, and check if they are converted at both main.php AND convert.php.  This is too much of a question extension to append to this page. @flash

Comment: I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192780/how-to-check-if-a-date-falls-between-two-days-of-a-week/58193410#58193410). It's not similar. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Comment: Thanks. The answer given by the user is close but still getting failed at some cases.

Comment: I need to replicate the fault.  Please modify this script to represent a failing case. https://3v4l.org/LS0mk I don't live in Pennsylvania anymore, so I would appreciate it if you would express the failing datetime in a non-relative manner (give me a static/literal datetime value).  What php version are you running? Are you certain that the datetime object's timezone is being recognized? Dump each object to see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'convert.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id: target}, //change to what you want
            success: function(res)
            {   
            },
            error: function(res)
            {
            }
        })
```

To this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'convert.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id: target}, //change to what you want
        success: function(res)
        {   
//You can add $(".go-btn").html('completed'); to here, but I prefer the other way.
        },
        error: function(res)
        {
// This is unnecessary if you are not gonna make it do anything if error occurs.
        }
    }) 
.done(function(data) {
$('.go-btn').html('Completed!');
//This fires when AJAX call suceeds the process. As a side note, "data" is what your .php code outputs, so you can do whatever you want to do with it.
});
```

And also see my comments.
I hope this helps.