# How to use system command in php?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am working on a PHP code as shown below in which **conversion of mp4 into mp3 is happening at Line B**.

I have added **if block after system command** to print **Conversion Completed**  on the webpage once the conversion is complete but it doesn't seem to work.

Php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['id']))
{
    for($i=0; $i <count($mp4_files); $i++) {
        if($i == $_POST['id']) {
            $f = $mp4_files[$i];
            $parts = pathinfo($f); 
            switch ($parts['extension'])
            {  
            case 'mp4' :
                $filePath = $src_dir . DS . $f;

                print_r($f);  // Line A        

                system('ffmpeg -i ' . $filePath . ' -map 0:2 -ac 1 ' . $destination_dir . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3', $result);  // Line B

                if($result)
                {
                    echo "Conversion Completed";
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the PHP code above so that once the conversion is complete; on the webpage, it should print `Conversion Completed`.

Comment: Why are you using a `for` loop? All you need is `$f = $mp4_files[$_POST['id']]`.

Comment: @Barmar You are right. I will minimize my code for sure. But if I want to print something on the webpage after the conversion is complete. Can I add                 `if($result)
                {
                    echo "Conversion Completed";
                }`

Comment: See the answers that people have posted and the comments below them.

Comment: Ok sure, I am waiting for the reply of @AbraCadaver

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shell_exec` to get a return value and then put that in an if statement like this

```php
$output = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i ' . $filePath . ' -map 0:2 -ac 1 ' . $destination_dir . DS . $parts['filename'] . '.mp3');
if ($output) {
   echo "Conversion Completed!";
   // or redirect here
}
```

Also, make sure to sanitize your inputs as they are exposed to a CLI interface.

Comment: _**Note**:

This function can return NULL both when an error occurs or the program produces no output. **It is not possible to detect execution failures using this function**. exec() should be used when access to the program exit code is required._

Comment: Also, what if `$output` = _Invalid data found when processing input_

Comment: It `$output` is null then `else` will execute. The OP requires if the conversion is complete or not @AbraCadaver

Comment: I don't think so its reaching inside if block because I added this `if(1) { echo "Conversion Completed"; }` and its not going inside in it as well.

Comment: That means there's a little problem in your code. Try a new file and put static values in my example and see. @flash

Comment: @weegee Majority of code is posted in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533375/how-to-change-button-text-in-js-ajax-upon-process-completion-in-php). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @weegee Let me know if you had a look.

Comment: @flash the code you provided there and here is same. What should work isn't working in your code. The problem isn't on our side. Do check for any errors and I'm happy to help you here